# docker: 'notary' is not a docker command

Tags: docker, notary

**docker: 'notary' is not a docker command**
The above error is getting in docker ce (20.10.2~3-0~ubuntu-bionic).
is it working in only enterprise edition ?

Comment: Please add more details, what are you trying to do, what is your environment and etc..

Answer (score 1):

`notary` is a standalone executable. See the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/notary/advanced_usage/).

```
notary --help
```